Is short help in a modal dialog a good idea?
I want to show some short help in modal dialogs. For example, a user works with some tool and doesn't know how to do something. He clicks Help button and short help is displayed to him in a modal dialog. How do you think it is a good idea to do this way?

It would be advisable to provide references or mockups for this type of question than to ask for solutions, as it will give the community more context and result in higher quality answers.

One cool way to show the Help feature is the one implemented in the Figma app. This non-intrusive modal allows the user to see some of the keyboard shortcuts and use them while you still see the different combinations to hide/show the panels or use the tools.



It depends on whether it is a new user or a veteran of that particular application. If he is a new user it would help as some processes are complicated and require a guide to complete while some don't require one. On the other hand, if the main users are veterans help can be optional due to previous experience of the app.
The other factor is the complexity of the task if it's something like signing a paper then a short one-time guide will do. On the other hand, if it's a form people aren't used to with many fields and authentication help will be beneficial.
